# Compare last GPS and current GPS data

Tags: php, mysql, sockets, session, caching

I have a project where i need to send GPS coordinates via. socket in every 6 seconds. The coordinates are stored in a MYsql database. I run a query every 6 seconds and if the last position is different from the current position the application sends the data to the remote server. In the browser it works like a charm but in the terminal i can't use Sessions.

I tried apc_add but according to the PHP manual it is removed a long time ago.

What is the most common way to do a comparsion like that? Store the last coordinates into the database or a text file? Or is there a way to sotore it in run time?

**Here is my main code: **

```
<?php 
require 'bootstrap.php';

use App\Libs\appServiceProvider;
use App\Libs\socketServiceProvider;
use Socket\Raw\Factory;
use App\Models\Koordinata;

$app = new appServiceProvider;


if (empty($_SESSION['lat']) || empty($_SESSION['lon'])) {
    $_SESSION['lat'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['lon'] = 0;
}

$lastLat = $_SESSION['lat'];
$lastLon = $_SESSION['lon'];

$currentLat = $app->getAllCoordinatesByFszgId($application['fszgId'])->last()->lat;
$currentLon = $app->getAllCoordinatesByFszgId($application['fszgId'])->last()->lon;

if ($lastLat != $currentLat && $lastLon != $currentLon) {
    $factory = new Factory();
    $socket = $factory->createClient('REMOTEADDRESSE');
    echo "Kapcsolat létrehozva\n";
    $socket->write("MESSAGE");
    echo "Üzenet elküldve\n";
    var_dump("Válasz: " . $socket->read(8192));
    $socket->close();
} else {
    echo "Idle";
    $log->addDebug("GPS data NOT CHANGED! STATUS IDLE!");
}

$_SESSION['lat'] = $app->getAllCoordinatesByFszgId($application['fszgId'])->last()->lat;
$_SESSION['lon'] = $app->getAllCoordinatesByFszgId($application['fszgId'])->last()->lon;

 ?>
```

Comment: When running in terminal you could simply run your script in and endless loop, maybe use sleep() to avoid active waiting. `while(true) { sleep(1); ... }

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I did it with database and works fine. Here is the code:

```
<?php 
require 'bootstrap.php';

use App\Libs\appServiceProvider;
use App\Libs\socketServiceProvider;
use Socket\Raw\Factory;
use App\Models\Koordinata;
use App\Models\TempKoordinata;

$app = new appServiceProvider;

$last = TempKoordinata::find(1);
if(!empty($last)) { 
    $lastLat = $last->lat;
    $lastLon = $last->lon;
} else {
    $temp = new TempKoordinata();
        $temp->id = 1;
        $temp->lat = 0;
        $temp->lon = 0;
    $temp->save();
    $log->addDebug('No data to compare! Empty tempCoordinate table! Set values to ZERO!');
}

$currentLat = $app->getAllCoordinatesByFszgId($application['fszgId'])->last()->lat;
$currentLon = $app->getAllCoordinatesByFszgId($application['fszgId'])->last()->lon;

if ($lastLat != $currentLat && $lastLon != $currentLon) {
    /*$factory = new Factory();
    $socket = $factory->createClient('REMOTE');
    echo "Kapcsolat létrehozva\n";
    $socket->write("MESSAGE");
    echo "Üzenet elküldve\n";
    var_dump("Válasz: " . $socket->read(8192));
    $socket->close();*/
    echo "Sending\n";
} else {
    echo "Idle\n";
    $log->addDebug("GPS data NOT CHANGED! STATUS IDLE!");
}

TempKoordinata::destroy(1);

//Elmentjük a mostani GPS koordinátát
$count = TempKoordinata::all();
//Ha üres az adatbázis akkor elmentjük a koordinátákat
if ($count->count() == 0) {
    $temp = new TempKoordinata();
        $temp->id = 1;
        $temp->lat = $currentLat;
        $temp->lon = $currentLon;
    $temp->save();
} else {
    $log->addDebug("More than one item in the temp table!");
}

 ?>
```